# How To Use 'Select Row Number()' With Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012, row-number

I tried to Use `ROW_NUMBER()` clause to retrieve a specific row number

when i execute this query

```
SELECT 
student.Aca_num,id_num,student.name,dob,pic,class.name,
student.tell,student.mobile1,mobile2,student.Email,nach.name,dist,notes
FROM
student,[user],users_classes,class,nach
WHERE
((class.ID)=student.class)
and
((nach.ID)=student.nach)
and
((student.class)=users_classes.Class_ID)
AND
((users_classes.[User_ID])=[user].ID)
AND
(([user].ID)=3)
```

[image: the result of the Query]

now i Need to use `Row Number()` with this Query to retrieve only one row by specify row number .

I use `Row Number()` Like this

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) AS Row, * FROM Student) AS EMP
WHERE Row = 3
```

this query return `third` row of student table

but there is an error when using `Row Number()` with multiple Tables such as (student,class)

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY student.name) AS Row, * FROM Student,Class) AS EMP
WHERE Row = 3
```

it gives me this Error

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 10 The column 'Name' was specified
>   multiple times for 'EMP'.

how can I Use `Row Number()` clause with multiple Table to return the specific row number|

thanks in advance

Regards ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's nothing to do with `ROW_NUMBER()`.

In both your `Student` and `Class` tables, you have a column called `Name`. When you create a subquery, the column names in the result set must be distinct.

So don't use `*`, name columns explicitly, including (if you must have both names) an alias for one:

```
SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s.name) AS Row, s.Name as StudentName,c.Name as ClassName FROM Student s,Class c) AS EMP
WHERE Row = 3
```

Of course, at the moment, you're performing a Cartesian join between the two tables. It's more likely that you want to join the tables in some way, e.g.

```
... FROM Student s INNER JOIN Class c on s.class = c.id ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is useful;

```
;WITH Emp AS
(
            -- Avoid using reserved words like [Row] (changed to nRow)
    SELECT   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY student.name) AS nRow 
            -- You cannot use * because your tables have columns with matching names
            -- Make sure that the columns you require are unique in their name or are aliased
            -- to be unique
            ,S.Col AS Foo
            ,C.Col AS Bar 
    FROM Student    S
    --  Your FROM expression [FROM Student,Class] will result effectively in a CROSS JOIN
    --  Clarify your join condition if you do not want a cartesian product
    JOIN Class      C ON S.Col = C.Col
)
SELECT *
FROM Emp
WHERE nRow = 3
```